# Why is my DEBUG trap executed (w/ content redirected) in { echo foo; echo bar; } >file?

Tags: bash

this group `{ echo hello; echo world; }` does exactly what it says in a bash shell file. It outputs (`od -xa`)

```
0000000    6568    6c6c    0a6f    6f77    6c72    0a64
          h   e   l   l   o  nl   w   o   r   l   d  nl
0000014
```

---

If I have the following defined in my `.bashrc`, however:

```
show_command_in_title_bar()
{
    case "${BASH_COMMAND}" in
        *\033]O*|*\\e]0*)
            true;;
        my_prompt_command)
            true;;
        *)
            printf "\e]0;%s\a" "${BASH_COMMAND}";;
    esac
}

trap show_command_in_title_bar DEBUG
```

...and I run the following redirection:

```
{ echo hello; echo world; } > a
```

Then the file's content is:

```
0000000    5d1b    3b30    6365    6f68    6820    6c65    6f6c    6807
        esc   ]   0   ;   e   c   h   o  sp   h   e   l   l   o bel   h
0000020    6c65    6f6c    1b0a    305d    653b    6863    206f    6f77
          e   l   l   o  nl esc   ]   0   ;   e   c   h   o  sp   w   o
0000040    6c72    0764    6f77    6c72    0a64
          r   l   d bel   w   o   r   l   d  nl
0000052
```

I don't remotely understand what's happening. Piping the same group with `| od -xa` shows the correct result. Writing to the file with `| tee a` also works.

Why does an interactive `echo` trigger `DEBUG` ?

Comment: Can't reproduce that

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are running `bash`? What does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: /bin/bash 4.4.12(1)-release

Comment: It's sending cursor motion before the echo, and a bell after it. Do you have an alias for `echo`? Or maybe something in your .bashrc?

Comment: Might help to run `set -x` to log any surrounding shell commands -- that would pick up a trap, function, &c. getting involved. `strace` isn't very useful because everything here is builtins, so it's all attached to the same process.

Comment: Actually, what's the output of `echo $-`?

Comment: No alias for echo. Using the builtin. Yes, typing this exactly.

Comment: echo $- outputs himBHs

Comment: Again, what does `set -x` log?

Comment: Ok, i get it. Updating question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEBUG traps are, by default, disabled for:

- shell functions
- command substitutions
- commands executed in a subshell environment

Pipelines run in subshells, so the `| tee a` instance has the trap disabled.

Command groupings without any subshell, however, are none of these three categories. Thus, the trap executing (and printing the content you asked of it) is in line with correct, documented behavior.

---

My primary advice is not to (ab)use a DEBUG trap for the purpose at hand.

My secondary advice is to direct content meant for human consumption to stderr, or (even better) `/dev/tty` -- not stdout. Thus, the line would become:

```
printf '\e]0;%s\a' "${BASH_COMMAND}" >/dev/tty
```

Alternately you could pre-open a file descriptor pointing to the TTY in your `.bashrc`. If using bash 4.1's automatic file descriptor allocation, the code in your `.bashrc` following the function definition would then become:

```
# open a file descriptor on the TTY *once*, instead of doing it over and over
# the trailing "||:" prevents this from being an error if it fails
exec {tty_fd}>/dev/tty ||:

# when running the code in the trap, use that file descriptor
# similarly, the ||: means our DEBUG trap never returns false
trap '[[ $tty_fd ]] && show_command_in_title_bar >&$tty_fd ||:' DEBUG
```

Comment: You say: "not to (ab)use a DEBUG trap" What other options are there?

Comment: Not trying to customize your shell with shiny things that make it less reliable and predictable? Submitting a patch to upstream bash to provide an *explicitly supported* hook for the purpose, with its output sent direct to the TTY?